# Gorm not creating full table from struct, how to fix?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Gorm create only id field, and ignores others fields

**Gorm: 1.25.7(latest)**

```golang
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Word struct {
    ID           uint
    symbols      string
    symbolsCount int
}


func main() {

    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("words.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Word{})

    db.Create(&Word{
        symbols:      "test",
        symbolsCount: len("test"),
    })

}
```

Tryed default from docs, and expect do that was written.

**It just create db, then create table words, and it contains only id.**

Comment: Can you share the link to the docs you have this example from? In general, unexported struct fields are not considered for any operation regarding gorm (or other libs, like json). So there might be an error in the docs, if you got the example from the official ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unexported struct fields (members starting with a lowercase letter) are not considered for any operation in GORM. The following updated code should yield the result you expected:

```golang
package main

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Word struct {
    ID           uint
    Symbols      string // <- Note the uppercase!
    SymbolsCount int    // <- Note the uppercase!
}


func main() {

    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("words.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Word{})

    db.Create(&Word{
        Symbols:      "test",
        SymbolsCount: len("test"),
    })

}
```